# Ubuntu not loading/running correctly

Tags: 12.04, lts

When I boot up I get just my desktop background, no menus or options. I can access terminal through recovery mode, but everything I try fails because of a missing package or something. I just updated from 11.10 to 12.04 lts, but I would really just like to reinstall with 13.04. Is there a way to do this from terminal/command line?

Comment: *"but I would really just like to reinstall with 13.04"* Just perform the 13.04 installation like any other Ubuntu installation. Download the ISO, put it on a flash drive or optical disc and run! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the terminal try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and reboot. This will download any required packages and also inform you of any errors if there is any.

To upgrade to 13.04, I beleive it is `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`